# Background knowledge on array in C++

Tags: c++

I use Clion(version 2018.02) to run the code. 
Here is the code:

```
int a[10]={0};
cout<<a[-1]<<endl;
cout<<a[10]<<endl;
```

After several testing, I found that every time a[-1]=0; However, the value of a[10] is always changing.
I wonder why the phenomenon happens on a[10] is not found on a[-1]. In other words, I guess that a[-1] should be changing as well.

#

**Actually I know those things above are undefined behaviors.**

However, in my mind, undefined behaviors always mean that they are randomized. What I'm doing is just creating bugs, and then see why a[-1] is always a specific number. So that I can know how it works inside the memory stream.

THANKS A LOT!!

Comment: Stop looking for sense where there is none. That code invokes *undefined behavior*. Therefore, there is no sense, and seeking it is a pointless effort.

Comment: Your code has a bug and it doesn't do what you expect because ... it has a bug. Fix the bug and the mystery will go away.

Comment: *After several testing* -- Well, you wasted a few minutes/hours/days of your time that you could have spent learning proper C++.

Comment: C++ is not Python.  `a[-1]` does not mean "the last element of `a`", it means "the -1th element of `a`".  There is no such element, and accessing it is undefined behaviour.  *Anything* can happen"

Comment: Undefined behaviour means, essentially, anything can happen.    There is no requirement that what happens makes sense to you or anyone else.

Comment: @WhozCraig Buffer overflows, or, more generally, accessing memory outside of an array, can sometimes lead to quite interesting results / exploits. Classical shellcode is based exactly on such undefined behavior.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the environment you are using. For example in vs13 I'm getting same garbage value for both `a[-1]` and `a[10]` in debug mode, but in release mode I'm getting garbage value for `a[-1]` and `0` for `a[10]`.

One thing that you can be sure about, in any case in these scenarios you will have undefined behavior and value should always be determine as garbage.